# Parsing a T-SQL statement into a TSqlObject

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, dac

`TSqlObject.GetScript()` converts the model into a script. I'd like to reverse the process and create a `TSqlObject` model from a script. How can this be done?